# How do i create an object using a function from a list of nested maps parse from json in Flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter, hashmap

I'm looking for help expanding on an earlier question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055854/how-do-i-return-the-values-of-a-nested-structure-with-a-list-of-maps-in-flutter/64056790?noredirect=1#comment113371072_64056790) which showed me one way to access the json data in `MovementDataSource`. In that case on the first page the user is presented a list of movements using a listview and `getMovements()`. After selecting a movement the user on page 2 is presented a list of variations via a listview and `getVariationsByMovement()`. Then after selecting the variation the user is presented page 3 that gives me access to all of the items in the singular `VariationModel`. (right now it's only variationName)

I have another use case where I am in another part of the application but need to jump directly to page 3 bypassing the user workflow of Page 1 and Page 2 above. At that moment I have access to the `String Movement` and the `String VariationName`. I'm looking for help - an example of a function that I could pass in those two variables and give me back a `VariationName` object to pass in the constructor of the link directly to page 3. In `MovementDataSource` below there is a `getVariation()` function I am hoping to have help with.

```
class MovementDataSource extends ChangeNotifier{

  List<Map> getAll() => _movement;

  List<String> getMovements()=> _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .map((item) => item.movement)
      .toList();

  getVariationsByMovement(String movement) => _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.movement == movement)
      .map((item) => item.variation)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .toList();

  VariationModel getVariation(String movement, String variation){
       **Return VariationModel from List _movement json**
  }


  List _movement = [
    {
      "movement": "Plank",
      "alias": "plank",
      "variation": [
        {"variationName": "High Plank"}, {"variationName": "Forearm Plank"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "movement": "Side Plank",
      "alias": "side plank",
      "variation": [
        {"variationName": "Side Plank Right"}, {"variationName": "Side Plank Left"},
      ],
    },
  ];
}

class MovementModel {
  MovementModel({
    this.movement,
    this.alias,
    this.variation,
  });

  String movement;
  String alias;
  List<VariationModel> variation;

  factory MovementModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MovementModel(
        movement: json["movement"],
        alias: json["alias"],
        variation: List<VariationModel>.from(
            json["variation"].map((x) => VariationModel.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "movement": movement,
        "alias": alias,
        "variation": List<dynamic>.from(variation.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class VariationModel {
  VariationModel({
    this.variationName,
  });

  String variationName;

  factory VariationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VariationModel(
        variationName: json["variationName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "variationName": variationName,
      };
}
```

An example of the Page 3 above - the direct target in this use case.

```
class TargetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VariationModel variation;
  SelectDefaultItemPage({this.variation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("test"),
        ),
        body: Text(variation.variationName));
  }
}
```

example of the source page that includes a direct link to page 3 target above. This is where the `getVariation()` function would be called passing a VariationModel to SourcePage above.

```
class SourcePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VariationModel variation;
  SelectDefaultItemPage({this.variation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("test"),
        ),
        body:FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                "Go to TargetPage",
              ),
              onPressed: () async {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => SourcePage(getVariation(movement: movement, variation: 
                            variation)));
              },
         )
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can pass `movementDataSource`, `movement` and `variation` to `SourcePage` 
And in `SourcePage` call

```
TargetPage(variation: movementDataSource.getVariation(
                            movement: movement,
                            variation: variation.variationName))
```

code snippet

```
VariationModel getVariation({String movement, String variation}) => _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.movement == movement)
      .map((item) => item.variation)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .where((e) => e.variationName == variation)
      .first;
...
onTap: () async {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => SourcePage(
                              movementDataSource: _movementDataSource,
                              movement: movement,
                              variation: vList[index])));
                },
                
...             
class SourcePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MovementDataSource movementDataSource;
  final String movement;
  final VariationModel variation;
  SourcePage({this.movementDataSource, this.movement, this.variation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        ...
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => TargetPage(
                        variation: movementDataSource.getVariation(
                            movement: movement,
                            variation: variation.variationName))));
          },
        ));     

...
class TargetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VariationModel variation;
  TargetPage({this.variation});
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

List<MovementModel> movementModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<MovementModel>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => MovementModel.fromJson(x)));
String movementModelToJson(List<MovementModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class MovementDataSource extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map> getAll() => _movement;

  List<String> getMovements() => _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .map((item) => item.movement)
      .toList();

// I'd  like this to return a list of movement.variation.variationName

  getVariationsByMovement(String movement) => _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.movement == movement)
      .map((item) => item.variation)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .toList();

  VariationModel getVariation({String movement, String variation}) => _movement
      .map((map) => MovementModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.movement == movement)
      .map((item) => item.variation)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .where((e) => e.variationName == variation)
      .first;

  List _movement = [
    {
      "movement": "Plank",
      "alias": "plank",
      "variation": [
        {"variationName": "High Plank"},
        {"variationName": "Forearm Plank"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "movement": "Side Plank",
      "alias": "side plank",
      "variation": [
        {"variationName": "Side Plank Right"},
        {"variationName": "Side Plank Left"},
      ],
    },
  ];
}

class MovementModel {
  MovementModel({
    this.movement,
    this.alias,
    this.variation,
  });

  String movement;
  String alias;
  List<VariationModel> variation;

  factory MovementModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MovementModel(
        movement: json["movement"],
        alias: json["alias"],
        variation: List<VariationModel>.from(
            json["variation"].map((x) => VariationModel.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "movement": movement,
        "alias": alias,
        "variation": List<dynamic>.from(variation.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class VariationModel {
  VariationModel({
    this.variationName,
  });

  String variationName;

  factory VariationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VariationModel(
        variationName: json["variationName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "variationName": variationName,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String movement = "Plank";
  MovementDataSource _movementDataSource = MovementDataSource();
  void _incrementCounter() {
    List<VariationModel> vList =
        _movementDataSource.getVariationsByMovement("Plank");

    for (int i = 0; i < vList.length; i++) {
      print(vList[i].variationName);
    }

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<VariationModel> vList =
        _movementDataSource.getVariationsByMovement(movement);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: vList.length,
          itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  vList[index].variationName.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                onTap: () async {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => SourcePage(
                              movementDataSource: _movementDataSource,
                              movement: movement,
                              variation: vList[index])));
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SourcePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MovementDataSource movementDataSource;
  final String movement;
  final VariationModel variation;
  SourcePage({this.movementDataSource, this.movement, this.variation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Source page"),
        ),
        body: FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            "Go to TargetPage",
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => TargetPage(
                        variation: movementDataSource.getVariation(
                            movement: movement,
                            variation: variation.variationName))));
          },
        ));
  }
}

class TargetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final VariationModel variation;
  TargetPage({this.variation});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Target page"),
        ),
        body: Text(variation.variationName));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm hoping between the answers you've provided I can start to triangulate how to get better at working with lists, maps and data. Do you know of any documentation or tutorials that focus on this one area using the `function() => data.doSomething.doSomething` constructions?

Comment: ＠nejas, you can reference https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2  and https://bezkoder.com/dart-list/